# How to get ID's from JSON array in groovy using the each method?

Tags: arrays, json, groovy

I'm trying to get a list of ID's from a JSON array in Groovy. I know how to get the ID's using the regular FOR loop, but I would like to know how to do the same with the **each** method. I'm not sure how to implement that. Does anyone have any idea?
Thank you in advance. Here's my code that works just fine using the regular for loop. However I would like to do it with the **each** method.

```
import groovy.json.*

def restresponse = '[{"id":5, "name":"Bob"},{"id":8, "name":"John"},{"id":12, "name":"Jim"},{"id":20, "name":"Sally"}]' 
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(restresponse)
def myListOfIDs = []

for (int i = 0; i < json.size; i++) {
 myListOfIDs.add(json[i].id) // getting all ID's for each SourceSystem
}
log.info(myListOfIDs) // This prints out all this IDs
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `json.each { ele ->
 myListOfIDs.add(ele.id)
}` ?

Comment: Or the even short `def myListOfIDs = json.collect { ele -> ele.id }`?

Comment: Your solution worked!! Thank you so much. Please post your solution so I can accept it as the correct answer

Comment: How did you test the first one? It just replaces the `for` loop in the example you posted (the rest would stay the same, although `log.info()` is not a Groovy built-in function I know of and I had to replace it with the standard `println` for testing)

Comment: I'm using SoapUI that why I'm using log.info. Your answer helped me a lot big time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way to perform this "conversion" is by using the Groovy's Collection [`collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)) method, e.g.:

```
def myListOfIDs = json.collect { ele -> ele.id }
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by @dmahapatro there's an even shorter possibility:

```
def myListOfIDs = json*.id
```

Comment: or just `json*.id` @HenryDev

Comment: I feel the answer should be edited to include this solution (since the answer mentions "the shortest way" and this is defintely it).